Asymptotic behavior of the Hermite functions
I would like to understand the asymptotic behavior of the Hermite function :
$$\psi_k(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^k k!}}H_k(x) e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}},$$
where $H_k(x)$ is the $k-$th Hermite polynomial. For instance, I would like to understand if for certain points as $x=a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ we have
$$\psi_k(a)\sim k^{-p},$$ with $p>0$. For me, it is actually enough to show that
$$\psi_k(a)\gtrsim k^{-p}$$
Thank you in advance!

for large $k$ the functions oscillate $\propto\cos(a\sqrt{2k}-k\pi/2)$; doesn't that invalidate your inequality?

Well, I know that there are some oscillations, but I was hoping that some results from Diophantine approximation theory would help me. For instance, I guess that, if $a$ is an irrational algebraic number, then $|\cos(a m )|\gtrsim 1/m^2$, but I don't know if this is still true if I substitute $m$ with $\sqrt{2 m}$. Before that anyway, I would like to find a good asymptotic expansion for $\psi_k(a)$ in order to understand if the lower order terms can bother me when I study the lower bound.
